# GKE Internal Ingress for Headless Service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I'm trying to create an internal ingress for inter-cluster communication with gke. The service that I'm trying to expose is headless and points to a kafka-broker on the cluster.

However when I try to load up the ingress, it says it cannot find the service?

```
Warning  Sync    3m22s (x17 over 7m57s)  loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer coilwp7v-redpanda-test-abc123-redpanda-japm3lph does not exist: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.target': 'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/abc-123/regions/europe-west2/targetHttpProxies/k8s2-tp-coilwp7v-redpanda-test-abc123-redpanda-japm3lph'. A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule., invalid
```

### Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-redpanda
  namespace: redpanda-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: redpanda-service
      port:
        number: 9092
```

### Service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redpanda-service
  namespace: redpanda-test
  annotations:
    io.cilium/global-service: "true"
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app: abc-panda
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: redpanda-cluster-0.redpanda-cluster.redpanda-test.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
    - port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
```

Comment: _"However when I try to load up the ingress, it says it cannot find the service?"_ - what makes you think so ? In the error message you get, there is nothing about the service. It says specifically: `"A reserved and active subnetwork is required in the same region and VPC as the forwarding rule."` Did you follow all the required steps, described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#before_you_begin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up ingress for internal load balancing requires you to configure a proxy-only subnet on the same VPC used by your GKE cluster.  This subnet will be used for the load balancers proxies.  You'll also need to create a fw rule to allow traffic as well.

Have a look at the [prereqs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#before_you_begin) for ingress and then look [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#configure-a-network) for info on how to setup the proxy-only subnet for your VPC.